# What is the most idiomatic way to convert a string to characters in Erlang?

Tags: string, erlang, codepoint

What is the most idiomatic way to convert this: `"helloworld"` to `["h","e","l","l","o","w","o","r","l","d"]` in Erlang ?

Comment: Well, the string is already a list of characters. What you are asking for is a list of one character strings/lists. One would wonder why you would like to do it for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The string is a list of characters

```
1> [$h, $e, $l, $l, $o, $w, $o, $r, $l, $d].
"helloworld"
```

So if you ask

> What is the most idiomatic way to convert a string to characters in
>   Erlang?

The answer is none, it already is a list of characters, you don't have to convert it.

If you ask, how to apply some function to the characters of the string, for example how to subtract 32.

```
2> [ X - 32 || X <- "helloworld" ].
"HELLOWORLD"
```

Or if you ask how to get a list of one character strings

```
3> [[X] || X <- "helloworld"].
["h","e","l","l","o","w","o","r","l","d"]
```

Answer (score 1):

an alternative to list comprehension in this simple case is the map function from lists module:

```
String = "helloworld",
lists:map(fun(X) -> [X] end, String).
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the code below:

```
1> [[X] || X <- "helloworld"].
["h","e","l","l","o","w","o","r","l","d"]
```